# Query creating Referential integrity

Tags: sql-server, xml

Below are the tables, which I'm currently working on.

I have to write a query that will provide referential integrity when adding data to the database. Rules are as followed:

A nonexistent stock item cannot be added to an order, A order item cannot be part of an order that does not exist and an order cannot be created for a nonexistent customer.  All new orders default to a value of false for their shipped flag and a default of the current days date when an order is created.

[image]
[image]

I created the expression below, but I'm wary of using it because I'm not sure if it will do what it should. Could you please confirm that it is correct? If it's not, could you please help me with changing it.

```
alter table default 'getdate()' for DatePlaced;alter table default false for OrderShipped; 
alter table orderitems add foreign key(StockItemId) references stock(StockItemId); 
alter table orderitems add foreign key(StockItemId) references stock(StockItemId); 
alter table orderitems add foreign key(OrderId) references orders(OrderId);
alter table orders add foreign key(CustomerId) references customers(CustomerId)
```

Comment: Did you try it? Does it meet the requirements of your assignment?

Comment: If it messes it up, just reload the table.  Presumably you're getting this from some sort of assignment and you could rebuild the tables.  And if you're doing this on real data, you'll need to know how to make things safer and undo your oopses anyway.